# unexpected result from gnu sort

Tags: sorting, unix, gnu-sort

when I try to sort the following text file 'input':

```
test1 3   
test3 2
test 4
```

with the command

```
sort input
```

the output is exactly the input. Here is the output of

```
od -bc input
```

:

```
0000000 164 145 163 164 061 011 063 012 164 145 163 164 063 011 062 012
          t   e   s   t   1  \t   3  \n   t   e   s   t   3  \t   2  \n
0000020 164 145 163 164 011 064 012
          t   e   s   t  \t   4  \n
0000027
```

It's just a tab separated file with two columns. When I do

```
sort -k 2
```

The output changes to

```
test3 2
test1 3
test 4
```

which is what I would expect. But if I do

```
sort -k 1
```

nothing changes with respect to the input, whereas I would expect 'test' to sort before 'test1'. Finally, if I do

```
cat input | cut -f 1 | sort
```

I get

```
test
test1
test3
```

as expected. Is there a logical explanation for this? What exactly is sort supposed to do by default, something like:

```
sort -k 1
```

?

My version of sort:

```
sort (GNU coreutils) 7.4
```

Comment: Even with a natural sorting algorithm, the input (as shown) is already sorted.

Answer (score 7):

From the man pages:

> ***  WARNING  ***  The locale specified by the environment affects
>   sort
>          order.  Set LC_ALL=C to get the traditional sort order that uses
>   native
>          byte values.

So it seems **export LC_ALL=C** must help

Comment: GNU sort with LC_ALL=C does produce the traditional answer - which is what 'sort' on Solaris produces anyway.  Change the 'test3' line to 'Test3' and you get more differences.  The GNU answers are consistent with the sort order of '`ls`'.  It is surprising, though.

Comment: Thanks, for me, too, it produces the expected result. However, in my default locale en_US.UTF-8, both tab and space also sort before alhpanumeric characters. If sort is just doing a lexicographical sort on the entire line, it remains a little surprising for me, too.