# unix sort -n -t"," gives unexpected result

Tags: sorting, unix, csv, locale

unix numeric sort gives strange results, even when I specify the delimiter.

```
$ cat example.csv  # here's a small example
58,1.49270399401
59,0.000192136419373
59,0.00182092924724
59,1.49270399401
60,0.00182092924724
60,1.49270399401
12,13.080339685
12,14.1531049905
12,26.7613447051
12,50.4592437035

$ cat example.csv | sort -n --field-separator=,
58,1.49270399401
59,0.000192136419373
59,0.00182092924724
59,1.49270399401
60,0.00182092924724
60,1.49270399401
12,13.080339685
12,14.1531049905
12,26.7613447051
12,50.4592437035
```

For this example, sort gives the same result regardless if you specify the delimiter. I know if I set `LC_ALL=C` then sort starts to give expected behavior again. But I do not understand why the default environment settings, as shown below, would make this happen.

```
$ locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I've read from many other questions (e.g. [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/87763/4), [here](http://miles-to-code.blogspot.com/2009/06/why-isnt-my-unix-sort-working.html), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923464/unix-sort-ignores-whitespaces)) how to avoid this behavior in sort, but still, this behavior is incredibly weird and unpredictable and has caused me a week of heartache. Can someone explain why sort with default environment settings on Mac OS X (10.8.5) would behave this way? In other words: what is sort doing (with local variables set to en_US.UTF-8) to get that result?

I'm using

```
 sort 5.93                        November 2005

 $ type sort
 sort is /usr/bin/sort
```

## UPDATE

I've discussed this on the gnu-coreutils list and now understand why sort with english unicode default locale settings gave the output it did. Because in English unicode, the comma character "," is considered a numeric (so as to allow for comma's as thousand's (or e.g. hundreds) separators), and sort defaults to "being greedy" when it interprets a line, it read the example numbers as approximately

```
581.491...
590.000...
590.001...
591.492...
600.001...
601.492...
1213.08...
1214.15...
1226.76...
1250.45...
```

Although this was not what I had intended and chepner is right that to get the actual result I want, I need to specify that I want sort to key on only the first field. sort defaults to interpreting more of the line as a key rather than just the first field as a key.

This behavior of sort has been discussed in gnu-coreutil's [FAQ](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/faq/coreutils-faq.html#Sort-does-not-sort-in-normal-order_0021), and is further specified in [the POSIX description of sort](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html).

So that, as Eric Blake on the [gnu-coreutil's list put it](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2013-10/msg00014.html), if the field-separator is also a numeric (which a comma is) then "Without -k to stop things, [the field-separator] serves as BOTH a separator AND a numeric character - you are sorting on numbers that span multiple fields."

Comment: Maybe it's allowing the comma as thousands separator, and permitting it anywhere? Certainly a bug with `-t,` at least if that's the case.

Comment: what happens if you specify which columns are the key to sort on? i.e either `+0 -1` or `-k1`? Good luck.

Comment: "Without -k to stop things, [the field-separator] serves as BOTH a separator AND a numeric character - you are sorting on numbers that span multiple fields."   Actually, even when using -k I'm getting the same issue, which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @hendrick what is your Locale? Open a question and I will take a look.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure this is entirely correct, but it's close.

`sort -n -t,` will try to sort numerically by the given key(s). In this case, the key is a tuple consisting of an integer and a float. Such tuples cannot be sorted numerically.

If you explicitly specify which single keys to sort on with

```
sort -k1,1n -k2,2n -t,
```

it should work. Now you are explicitly telling `sort` to first sort on the first field (numerically), then on the second field (also numerically).

I suspect that `-n` is useful as a global option only if each line of the input consists of a single numerical value. Otherwise, you need to use the `-n` option in conjunction with the `-k` option to specify exactly which fields are numbers.

Comment: That's interesting.  `sort -k1,1n` works. But what is it doing when I enter `sort -k1n` (which does not work) ? Why does it try to sort a tuple instead of defaulting to the first value in a line? And when I specify the first column with `-k1n` why doesn't that sort by the first column?

Comment: `-k<m>,<n>` sorts using fields `m` through `n`, inclusive. `-k<m>` uses fields `m` through the last field. You have to use `-k<m>,<m>` to sort on exactly field `m`. Using `-k1` is legal, but identical to not using `-k` at all. Something like `-k2` is more common (sort on all fields but the first).

Comment: Thank you very much for your responses. That makes sense (though counter-intuitive), but then not including the -k at all should mean that it sorts on all fields -- using the first field first. Why isn't it doing this?

Comment: The distinction is that `sort -n` and `sort -k1 -n` uses a single key with a non-numeric value (specifically, a tuple of an int and a float), while `sort -k1,1n -k2,2n` uses two keys, each of which is a single numerical value. You are using "field" and "key" as synonyms, which they are not. A key can consist of 1 or more fields, and `sort` can use one or more keys (by sorting on the first key, then the second key, etc).

Comment: That makes sense. But why can't tuples of numerics be sorted numerically?

Comment: Because tuples aren't numbers. Also, `tuple` is probably a poor choice of words on my part. `sort` seems to simply concatenate the fields that make up a key into a single string. But the fact is, `sort` simply doesn't distinguish between the fields used to create such a key. You can argue that perhaps it should, but it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you. That completely answers my question. The next step is to see where the conversation on this is at in unix! Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

Use sort --debug to find out what's going on.
I've used that to explain in detail your issue at:
http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2013-10/msg00004.html

Comment: Thanks so much for the link! I finally understand my issue with numeric sort - in my case `sort` was ignoring parts of numbers after decimal dot `.` (as my locale uses coma `,`) and then the full line for secondary sort order. I coudn't figure out what order it was giving me, now I know.

Comment: This is a common enough issue that we added more info to `sort --debug` re thousands grouping and decimal separators https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/commit/bafff001

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
cat example.csv | sort
```

instead of

```
cat example.csv | sort -n --field-separator=,
```

then it would give correct output. Use this command, hope this is helpful to you.

Note: I tested with "sort (GNU coreutils) 7.4"

Comment: Thanks -- and this is interesting (I wonder why it gives this behavior). However it does not answer the question. The question is: when you ask unix to sort numeric, why doesn't it sort numeric? What is it doing in this case?

Comment: With no options, you are simply performing a lexicographic sort, which appears to work on this input because all the leading integer values are two-digit strings.